# Filtering WP_Query

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, filters, archives

I'm developing a site that uses a Artist custom post type and I need to query all posts of this type in a page template. I need to set the **is_post_type_archive** property to true too to filter this query using the **posts_orderby** filter. I'm using the following code, but it seems WordPress is ignoring the third line:

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'artist');
$wp_query = new WP_Query( array_merge( $args, array('nopaging' => true) ) );
$wp_query->is_post_type_archive = true;
```

This is the filter:

```
function artist_posts_orderby( $orderby )
{
    if (is_post_type_archive('artist')) {
        $orderby = "RIGHT(post_title, LOCATE(' ', REVERSE(post_title)) - 1) ASC";
    }
    return $orderby;
}
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'artist_posts_orderby' );
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote the code and now it works

The loop:

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'artist');
$wp_query = new WP_Query( array_merge( $args, array('nopaging' => true) ) );
```

The filter:

```
function theme_posts_orderby( $orderby, $query )
{
    if ($query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'artist') {
        // order artists by last name
        $orderby = "RIGHT(post_title, LOCATE(' ', REVERSE(post_title)) - 1) ASC";
    }
    return $orderby;
}
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'theme_posts_orderby', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

WP_Query retrieves posts right when it's created (in constructor). By the time you are modifying property it is already processed and results are stored.

You probably shouldn't be reusing main `$wp_query` object and global methods for this either.

Your question doesn't give enough details to suggest how to target query more precisely for your requirements, however there is always simple approach - add your filter right before query and remove right after.